# Make arm point towards mouse direction

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, mouseevent, mouse

I have a SVG image of a person which I want to animate slightly. I want to make the arm point towards the mouse. However I can't seem to get it to work. Currently I have this:

**[View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/coen-hallie/pen/bGELLGO)**

As you can see the hand is fixed but the shoulder is loose which should be the opposite. Only when I point my mouse towards the shoulder the hand is correct again.

I use the following code

```
  document.querySelector('#app')
    .addEventListener('mousemove', mascotArm);
    function mascotArm() {
      var arm = document.querySelectorAll('.arm');
      arm.forEach(function(arm) {
        let x = (arm.getBoundingClientRect().right);
        let y = (arm.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        let radian = Math.atan2(event.pageX - x, event.pageY + y);
        let rot = (radian * (90 / Math.PI))
        arm.style.transform = 'rotate('+ rot + 'deg)';
      })
    }
```

I've tried the following code, but I wasn't able to implement it correctly in the SVG image

```
var cv = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
cv.width = 1224;
cv.height = 768;
document.body.appendChild(cv);

var centerX = 300, centerY = 200;

var arm = new Image();
arm.onload = function() {
    drawArrow(0);
};
var arm = document.querySelectorAll('.arm')


function drawArm(angle) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.drawImage(arm, -arm.width / 2, -arm.height / 2);
  ctx.restore();
}

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var dx = e.pageX - centerX;
  var dy = e.pageY - centerY;
  var theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    drawArm(theta);
};
```

**Desired solution**

My desired solution would be that I can move my mouse on the page and that the arm is pointing towards my mouse. If possible it would be awesome if it can only move 90 degrees so that it doesn't make weird rotations.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will need a transform origin for the rotation of the .arm. For example you may try `.arm{transform-origin: 280px 200px;}`. In the code I've added a small red circle to mark the rotation hub. You can delete the circle and change the position of the hub. Please observe that I'm using the hub position in JavaScript. You will have to change it there too.

In JavaScript it's `Math.atan2(y,x)` not <del>Math.atan2(x,y)</del>. Please read about [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2).

Also the arm has a different angle inside the .arm box. You will need to to take in consideration this angle too. In order to understand what happens I've added a black rectangle as big as the bounding box of the arm. You may try `arm.style.transform = 'rotate('+ (rot - 20) + 'deg)';`

Also you ar listening the mouse over the app. As you can see I'm listening the mouse over the svg elemet. I suppose you need the doctorat the right side of the app. In order to keep it there I have `#app {height:100vh;` The app is now as wide as it's parent. Also `svg{width:100%; height:100%}` This will stretch the svg element over the app. In order to keep the doctor to the right I'm using `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet"`

```js
let svg = document.querySelector('#svg'); svg.addEventListener('mousemove', mascotArm);
//the hub position
let X = 280;
let Y = 200;

    function mascotArm(event) {
      var arm = document.querySelector('.arm');
       let p = getMousePositionSVG(event)
        let x = p.x;
        let y = p.y;
        let radian = Math.atan2(Y-y, X-x);
        let rot = (radian * (180 / Math.PI))
        arm.style.transform = 'rotate('+ (rot - 20) + 'deg)';
      
    }

//a function to calculate the mouse position over an svg element
function getMousePositionSVG(event) {
var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
point.x = event.clientX;
point.y = event.clientY;
point = point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
return point;
}
```

```css
#app {
  background: #efefef;
  height:100vh 
}
svg{width:100%; height:100%}
.arm{transform-origin: 280px 200px;}
```

```html
<div id="app">
<svg viewBox="0 0 458 753" fill="none" id="svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax meet">
  <g class="Layer 1">
    <g class="Group">
      <g class="Group_2">
        <g class="Group_3">
          <path d="M286.306 353l-18.063 197.3-14.569 144.54s7.896 11 37.606 6l15.695-151.5 19.149-124.5h15.299l10.167 276s12.831 10 36.619 1l-4.737-355.3-97.166 6.46z" fill="#303942" class="Vector_7"/>
          <path d="M373.265 701.34a48.73 48.73 0 0014.609-2.5l-4.639-347.6-89.033 5.9-17.767 193.7-14.312 142.4c2.171 1.6 7.6 4.7 18.853 4.7a73.728 73.728 0 0010.462-.8l15.3-148.3 19.741-128.2h22.998l10.266 277.8a29.95 29.95 0 0013.522 2.9z" fill="#252D33" class="Vector_8"/>
          <path d="M274.856 199.44s3.257 100.3 9.673 151.2c0 0 24.479 11.1 63.566 9.5 27.638-1.1 35.534-7.1 35.534-7.1l40.075-162.7s-20.432-11.9-62.481-11.9l-19.543 18.3s-5.331-14.2-15.793-17c-15.793 1.1-32.277 6-50.834 9.1l-.197 10.6z" fill="#148C78" class="Vector_9"/>
          <path d="M341.778 196.64l5.034-17.8 11.154 5.2-16.188 12.6z" fill="#056351" class="Vector_10"/>
          <path d="M349.477 161.24c4.936-2.4 9.476-6.9 12.931-13l.493 2.6.296 25.5c-8.982 1.2-19.247-4.1-28.526-14.6a17.467 17.467 0 007.458 1.399 17.467 17.467 0 007.348-1.899z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_11"/>
          <path d="M340.298 180.44l1.48 16.2-9.179-11.5 7.699-4.7z" fill="#056351" class="Vector_12"/>
          <path d="M350.168 185.14a41.914 41.914 0 01-13.226.5l-6.219 7.5 5.429 7.9-21.222 125.3 16.385 16.6 20.038-14.5-4.639-126.6 6.81-9.8-3.356-6.9z" fill="#73C8D2" class="Vector_13"/>
          <path d="M315.029 179.34l13.72 18.8 11.549-17.7-18.162-12.3-7.107 11.2z" fill="#0C7561" class="Vector_14"/>
          <path d="M412.353 247.44l-19.445 75 6.712 198.2-66.33 14.6-9.674-19.7-9.673 20.9-54.683-13.8s13.424-289.4 15.892-333.6l28.032-9.1 34.547 115.5 41.299-118.2s43.43 11.8 53.794 14.4" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_16"/>
          <path d="M335.165 164.64c17.964-2.3 38.199-17.3 42.838-27a17.044 17.044 0 012.863-4.6c16.385 3 24.38-31.4 13.621-36.1-.395-.2-.888-.3-1.283-.5a10.522 10.522 0 017.6.5c10.759 4.7 2.863 39.1-13.621 36.1a15.652 15.652 0 00-2.863 4.6c-4.639 9.8-24.873 24.7-42.838 27a33.045 33.045 0 01-7.699.1c.463.016.926-.017 1.382-.1z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_17"/>
          <path d="M399.225 102.84c-5.626-2.9-10.562 6.3-10.858 16.1 4.639-.7 5.429 4.7 2.764 8.6 9.278 1.9 14.115-21.6 8.094-24.7z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_18"/>
          <path d="M432.884 191.64c-8.094-2.1-40.174-13.5-53.795-14.4l-41.259 118.1-34.547-115.5-17.471 44c-2.171 40.1-18.359 258.6-20.235 295l46.491 12.4 11.154-23.6 11.943 22.3 61.888-15.3 4.442-196.4 14.411-98.3" fill="#F2F2F2" class="Vector_19"/>
          <g class="Group_6">
            <path d="M375.733 274.74v-8.2h-6.811a2.956 2.956 0 01-1.923-1.186 3.028 3.028 0 01-.544-2.214 2.887 2.887 0 01.808-1.681 2.824 2.824 0 011.659-.819h19.544a2.935 2.935 0 012.018.674c.567.47.942 1.136 1.053 1.87a3.035 3.035 0 01-.455 2.103 2.964 2.964 0 01-1.728 1.253h-7.6v8.2a3.118 3.118 0 01-1.064 1.796 3.04 3.04 0 01-3.893 0 3.118 3.118 0 01-1.064-1.796zm-6.811-12.8a1.664 1.664 0 00-1.215.427c-.333.3-.535.722-.561 1.173-.027.451.125.894.421 1.231.296.338.713.542 1.158.569h8.39v9.4c.038.446.243.861.573 1.159.331.298.762.455 1.204.441a1.774 1.774 0 001.066-.519c.287-.291.468-.672.513-1.081v-9.4h8.094c.445.027.882-.127 1.215-.427.333-.3.535-.722.561-1.173a1.711 1.711 0 00-.421-1.231 1.674 1.674 0 00-1.158-.569h-19.84z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_20"/>
            <path d="M368.922 260.64h19.544a2.935 2.935 0 012.018.674c.567.47.942 1.136 1.053 1.87a3.035 3.035 0 01-.455 2.103 2.964 2.964 0 01-1.728 1.253h-7.6v8.2a3.007 3.007 0 01-1.171 1.949 2.931 2.931 0 01-2.185.551 2.943 2.943 0 01-1.636-.843 3.015 3.015 0 01-.832-1.657v-8.2h-6.771a2.954 2.954 0 01-1.924-1.186 3.028 3.028 0 01-.543-2.214 2.433 2.433 0 01.629-1.721 2.375 2.375 0 011.641-.779h-.04zm.04-1.2c-1.1 0-2.154.443-2.932 1.23a4.23 4.23 0 00-1.214 2.97 4.23 4.23 0 001.214 2.97 4.118 4.118 0 002.932 1.23h5.626v6.9a4.254 4.254 0 001.361 2.904 4.147 4.147 0 002.982 1.096 4.073 4.073 0 002.751-1.213 4.174 4.174 0 001.197-2.787v-6.9h5.626c1.1 0 2.154-.442 2.932-1.23a4.23 4.23 0 001.214-2.97 4.23 4.23 0 00-1.214-2.97 4.123 4.123 0 00-2.932-1.23h-19.543z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_21"/>
            <path d="M368.922 259.44h19.544c1.1 0 2.154.443 2.931 1.23a4.227 4.227 0 011.215 2.97 4.227 4.227 0 01-1.215 2.97 4.114 4.114 0 01-2.931 1.23h-5.626v6.9a4.254 4.254 0 01-1.361 2.904 4.147 4.147 0 01-2.982 1.096 4.069 4.069 0 01-2.751-1.213 4.17 4.17 0 01-1.197-2.787v-6.9h-5.627a4.15 4.15 0 01-2.923-1.239 4.258 4.258 0 01-1.222-2.961 4.187 4.187 0 011.202-2.982 4.095 4.095 0 012.943-1.218zm0-1.3a5.35 5.35 0 00-2.08.413 5.41 5.41 0 00-1.764 1.192 5.485 5.485 0 00-1.177 1.787 5.554 5.554 0 00-.407 2.108 5.475 5.475 0 00.391 2.117 5.424 5.424 0 001.175 1.796 5.334 5.334 0 001.772 1.19 5.28 5.28 0 002.09.397h4.343v5.7a5.492 5.492 0 001.686 3.646 5.354 5.354 0 003.694 1.484 5.354 5.354 0 003.694-1.484 5.496 5.496 0 001.685-3.646v-5.7h4.343a5.351 5.351 0 002.081-.413 5.42 5.42 0 001.764-1.192 5.482 5.482 0 001.176-1.787 5.536 5.536 0 00.408-2.108 5.475 5.475 0 00-.391-2.117 5.424 5.424 0 00-1.175-1.796 5.328 5.328 0 00-3.863-1.587h-19.445z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_22"/>
            <path d="M378.595 249.44c.391 0 .773.117 1.097.337a2.019 2.019 0 01.299 3.077 1.956 1.956 0 01-3.037-.303 2.017 2.017 0 01.246-2.525 1.96 1.96 0 011.395-.586zm0-1.2c-.644 0-1.273.194-1.809.556a3.295 3.295 0 00-1.2 1.481 3.343 3.343 0 00-.185 1.907c.125.64.436 1.228.891 1.689a3.219 3.219 0 003.55.716 3.27 3.27 0 001.462-1.216c.358-.542.549-1.18.549-1.833a3.32 3.32 0 00-.24-1.268 3.268 3.268 0 00-.705-1.074 3.216 3.216 0 00-2.313-.958z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_23"/>
            <path d="M378.595 248.24c.645 0 1.274.194 1.81.556.536.363.953.878 1.2 1.481.246.603.311 1.267.185 1.907a3.316 3.316 0 01-.891 1.689 3.219 3.219 0 01-3.55.716 3.27 3.27 0 01-1.462-1.216 3.327 3.327 0 01-.549-1.833 3.423 3.423 0 01.982-2.306 3.334 3.334 0 012.275-.994zm0-1.3c-.878 0-1.737.264-2.467.758a4.489 4.489 0 00-1.636 2.02 4.56 4.56 0 00-.253 2.6 4.508 4.508 0 001.216 2.304 4.389 4.389 0 004.84.975 4.45 4.45 0 001.994-1.657c.488-.74.748-1.61.748-2.5a4.585 4.585 0 00-1.315-3.168 4.461 4.461 0 00-3.127-1.332z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_24"/>
            <path d="M378.595 246.94c.879 0 1.738.264 2.468.758a4.489 4.489 0 011.636 2.02 4.56 4.56 0 01.253 2.6 4.523 4.523 0 01-1.216 2.304 4.389 4.389 0 01-4.84.975 4.45 4.45 0 01-1.994-1.657 4.542 4.542 0 01-.748-2.5 4.636 4.636 0 011.331-3.151 4.522 4.522 0 013.11-1.349zm0-1.2c-1.132 0-2.239.34-3.18.977a5.794 5.794 0 00-2.109 2.603 5.875 5.875 0 00-.325 3.352 5.818 5.818 0 001.566 2.969 5.66 5.66 0 006.239 1.257 5.742 5.742 0 002.57-2.136 5.854 5.854 0 00.964-3.222 5.84 5.84 0 00-1.676-4.101 5.688 5.688 0 00-4.049-1.699z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_25"/>
          </g>
          <path d="M303.184 179.84l34.547 115.5-30.302-37.4 2.369-24.6-16.089-4.9 1.579-47.3 7.896-1.3z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_26"/>
          <path d="M303.382 180.14l-4.343.7-1.086 43.8 15.892 5-2.567 25.4 22.999 28.4-30.895-103.3z" fill="#EAEAEA" class="Vector_27"/>
          <path d="M333.092 318.34c2.508 0 4.541-2.059 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.541 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_28"/>
          <path d="M331.019 349.04c2.508 0 4.541-2.06 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_29"/>
          <path d="M329.637 381.04c2.508 0 4.541-2.06 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_30"/>
          <path d="M327.565 411.74c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_31"/>
          <path d="M326.676 439.34c2.508 0 4.541-2.059 4.541-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.541-4.6-2.507 0-4.54 2.059-4.54 4.6 0 2.541 2.033 4.6 4.54 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_32"/>
          <path d="M324.505 470.04c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_33"/>
          <path d="M323.222 498.24c2.507 0 4.54-2.06 4.54-4.6 0-2.541-2.033-4.6-4.54-4.6-2.508 0-4.541 2.059-4.541 4.6 0 2.54 2.033 4.6 4.541 4.6z" fill="#E8E8E8" class="Vector_34"/>
          <path d="M352.142 88.24c2.567-2.3 8.686-1.8 10.364.6.889.6 0 1.8-1.776 1.8h-3.415a3.91 3.91 0 00-2.567.6c-1.717-.1-4.343-1.9-2.606-3z" fill="#65433F" class="Vector_35"/>
          <path d="M332.895 120c.789 0 2.27 1.6 3.06 1.6 1.48 0 2.27 0 3.059-.8.79-.8 2.271 0 1.58 1.6-.691 1.6-3.06 2.5-4.639 2.5-1.58 0-4.64-1.6-5.33-3.3.789-.76 1.48-1.6 2.27-1.6z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_36"/>
          <path d="M332.796 153.74l1.086-1.1c1.086 0 2.171 2.3 1.086 2.3h-2.172c0-.1-1.086-.1 0-1.2z" fill="#F4876C" class="Vector_37"/>
          <path d="M396.955 104.84a4.065 4.065 0 00-1.913-.537 4.062 4.062 0 00-1.937.437c1.777-2 3.948-2.8 6.219-1.6 5.231 2.7 2.171 21-4.738 24.3 5.172-5.7 6.909-20.2 2.369-22.6z" fill="#E58370" class="Vector_38"/>
          <path d="M322.037 88.34c-2.566-2.4-8.686-1.8-10.364.6-.888.6 0 1.8 1.777 1.8h3.454a3.91 3.91 0 012.567.6c1.776-.1 4.343-1.9 2.566-3z" fill="#65433F" class="Vector_39"/>
          <path d="M378.99 177.24l6.811.3 3.948 42.4-19.642 4.4 6.712 26.4-37.212 39.3 39.383-112.8z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_40"/>
          <path d="M373.167 247.94l-6.91-27.4 19.939-4.5-3.554-38.6-3.454-.2-35.534 101.9 29.513-31.2z" fill="#EAEAEA" class="Vector_41"/>
        <path d="M296.176 190.54h-.395a19.546 19.546 0 00-13.621 5.5c-10.463 10.1-9.377 30.6-9.278 31.5.093.656.432 1.251.947 1.66.514.41 1.165.603 1.816.54a2.41 2.41 0 001.754-.723 2.49 2.49 0 00.714-1.777c0-.3-1.086-19.4 7.897-28a13.675 13.675 0 014.593-2.975 13.54 13.54 0 015.376-.925h.197a13.562 13.562 0 018.291 3.1c4.146 3.3 9.18 10.9 9.575 27.9a2.61 2.61 0 00.921 1.718c.516.43 1.177.638 1.843.582a2.36 2.36 0 001.798-.635 2.423 2.423 0 00.768-1.765c-.395-15.1-4.244-25.7-11.549-31.4a18.149 18.149 0 00-11.647-4.3z" fill="#006983" class="Vector_67"/>
        <g class="Group_13">
          <path d="M293.807 255.34a2.381 2.381 0 00-.714-1.647 2.311 2.311 0 00-1.655-.653l-4.245.5c-1.283.4-1.283 1.1-1.283 2 0 1 0 1.7 1.481 2l4.145.2a2.36 2.36 0 001.609-.74c.423-.447.66-1.041.662-1.66z" fill="#151E31" class="Vector_68"/>
          <path d="M290.55 255.44a2.712 2.712 0 012.27 1c-.418.429-.984.68-1.579.7l-2.566-.1c-.099-1.2.592-1.6 1.875-1.6z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_69"/>
          <path d="M289.563 254.24c-1.875.3-2.566 1.6-2.566 3.3-1.185-.3-1.185-1-1.185-1.9 0-.9 0-1.6 1.283-2l4.245-.5c.522 0 1.03.177 1.441.504.411.326.703.782.829 1.296a4.596 4.596 0 00-4.047-.7z" fill="#808184" class="Vector_70"/>
        </g>
        <g class="Group_14">
          <path d="M298.841 255.24a2.375 2.375 0 01.645-1.677 2.32 2.32 0 011.626-.723l4.343.3c1.381.3 1.283 1 1.381 1.9 0 1 0 1.7-1.381 2.1l-4.146.4a2.458 2.458 0 01-1.676-.663 2.523 2.523 0 01-.792-1.637z" fill="#151E31" class="Vector_71"/>
          <path d="M302.099 255.14a2.272 2.272 0 00-2.172 1.1c.429.401.996.616 1.579.6l2.567-.3c0-1.2-.691-1.54-1.974-1.4z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_72"/>
          <path d="M303.027 253.84c.379.016.751.11 1.094.277a2.8 2.8 0 01.897.692 2.851 2.851 0 01.674 2.131c1.184-.4 1.184-1.1 1.086-2-.099-.9 0-1.6-1.382-1.9l-4.343-.3a2.218 2.218 0 00-1.428.549c-.397.348-.66.826-.744 1.351a5.713 5.713 0 014.146-.8z" fill="#808184" class="Vector_73"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="ster-ogen">
      <path d="M318.43 112.35l8.72 3.42-3.63-8.61 6-7.27-9.34.73-5-7.89-2.18 9-9 2.28 8 4.88-.62 9.34 7.05-5.88z" fill="#F9FF00" class="Vector_74"/>
      <path d="M361.98 119.3l-.62-10 8.51-5.19-9.65-2.49-2.24-9.62-5.3 8.31-9.86-.83 6.33 7.68-3.84 9.13 9.24-3.63 7.43 6.64z" fill="#F9FF00" class="Vector_75"/>
    </g>
    <g class="blij">
      <path d="M334.671 148.64c-11.055-1.1-12.733-9-11.055-11.2 1.678-2.2 19.939-2.3 22.209 0 1.619 1.7-.592 11.2-11.154 11.2z" fill="#AA312D" class="Vector_76"/>
      <path d="M346.319 139.14a1.93 1.93 0 00-.592-1.7c-2.271-2.3-19.939-2.3-22.209 0 0 0-.593 1.1 0 1.7 7.304 2.2 15.102 1.7 22.801 0z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_77"/>
      <path d="M330.723 147.84a12.667 12.667 0 01-4.836-2.6c.493-.5 1.085-.5 1.579-1.1a17.076 17.076 0 015.527-.6 13.086 13.086 0 018.588 3.2 12.866 12.866 0 01-6.91 1.9 13.294 13.294 0 01-3.454-.7.884.884 0 01-.494-.1z" fill="#902622" class="Vector_78"/>
    </g>
    <g class="ogen">
      <path d="M358.065 113.64c4.143 0 7.501-3.627 7.501-8.1 0-4.474-3.358-8.1-7.501-8.1-4.143 0-7.502 3.626-7.502 8.1 0 4.473 3.359 8.1 7.502 8.1z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_79"/>
      <path d="M358.065 112.44c3.543 0 6.416-3.089 6.416-6.9 0-3.811-2.873-6.9-6.416-6.9-3.544 0-6.416 3.089-6.416 6.9 0 3.811 2.872 6.9 6.416 6.9z" fill="#5E3536" class="Vector_80"/>
      <path d="M360.039 104.14c.872 0 1.579-.761 1.579-1.7s-.707-1.7-1.579-1.7-1.579.761-1.579 1.7.707 1.7 1.579 1.7z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_81"/>
      <path d="M316.707 113.64c4.143 0 7.502-3.627 7.502-8.1 0-4.474-3.359-8.1-7.502-8.1s-7.502 3.626-7.502 8.1c0 4.473 3.359 8.1 7.502 8.1z" fill="#F2957C" class="Vector_82"/>
      <path d="M316.707 112.44c3.543 0 6.416-3.089 6.416-6.9 0-3.811-2.873-6.9-6.416-6.9s-6.416 3.089-6.416 6.9c0 3.811 2.873 6.9 6.416 6.9z" fill="#5E3536" class="Vector_83"/>
      <path d="M318.681 104.14c.872 0 1.579-.761 1.579-1.7s-.707-1.7-1.579-1.7-1.579.761-1.579 1.7.707 1.7 1.579 1.7z" fill="#fff" class="Vector_84"/>
    </g>
    <g class="arm" id="kk">
      <rect y="109" width="282" height="128" fill="black"/>
      <path d="M75.77 140.4l-8.785-3.8s-8.983-13.4-21.222-17.2a79.917 79.917 0 01-8.193-2.9 16.65 16.65 0 01-6.81-7.5s-5.627.5-1.481 7.8a22.565 22.565 0 006.613 6.4 67.371 67.371 0 01-10.759-3.4c-1.776-.8-12.437-5-16.385-6.9-1.875-.9-6.712-3.3-8.489.4-1.974 4.2 7.897 7.6 10.068 8.4 4.738 1.9 16.78 8.8 16.78 8.8s-8.093-2.6-9.475 2.2a4.26 4.26 0 00.296 3.1c1.184 2.4 2.862 2.5 2.862 2.5a4.809 4.809 0 00-1.579 2.521 4.86 4.86 0 00.197 2.979 5.87 5.87 0 001.962 2.366 5.76 5.76 0 002.875 1.034s-4.442 5.6 3.948 9c2.863 1.2 4.935 1.3 7.897 1.8 2.888.601 5.843.802 8.784.6a48.873 48.873 0 009.377-.9c1.876-.4 7.009 3.1 9.772 5.2a22.152 22.152 0 005.824 3.2l11.845-23.4-5.923-2.3z" fill="#F2AB8F" class="Vector_85"/>
      <path d="M84.949 140.3l-8.982-4.2-14.806 31.4 9.377 5.2 14.41-32.4z" fill="#148C78" class="Vector_86"/>
      <path d="M273.97 233.6l8.193-41.3s-168.984-14.9-194.55-56.5c0 0-19.938 21.6-22.307 37.7-.098 0 175.795 76.3 208.664 60.1z" fill="#F2F2F2" class="Vector_87"/>
      <path d="M254.328 237.2c-36.028-1.5-144.308-43-190.403-62.3 1.875-3.4 2.171-8.1 4.639-11.6 18.556 14.8 66.034 33.9 116.867 43.9 29.908 5.9 78.965 10.9 95.35 12.8l-.691 16c-5.231 1.2-25.071 1.2-25.762 1.2z" fill="#E5E5E5" class="Vector_88"/>
    </g>
  </g>
    
    <circle cx="280" cy="200" r="10" fill="red"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Enxaneta,

Just awesome, Thanks so much for your detailed explanation! This little animation was really something I wanted to add to my job assignment as the icing on the cake , let's see if it worked out!

Comment: @enxaneta Great answer! I noticed a small nuance.If the cursor is placed in the black zone of the hand, then you can rotate the hand 360 degrees